# Design Hybrid MPI/OpenMP to avoid idle root process without blocking slave process from sending

Tags: mpi, openmp

I am very new to hybrid parallelization and I have a question on designing my hybrid parallelization approach.

I am implementing a computation over multiple time frames, and each frame has millions of points. I use a cluster with 6 nodes, and each node has 20 threads. I assign each node to only 1 MPI process, and it utilizes 20 shared threads. Here is the main line of my job file

```
mpiexec -ppn 1 -np 6 -env OMP_NUM_THREADS 20 ./mycode
```

Suppose I have to compute 60 time frames. Here is my parallelization:

- I used MPI to parallelize over *time steps*. If there are 6 nodes with 60 time frames, I can assign each node to compute 10 time frames. Time frame computations are independent, so MPI process are not communicating except with root process.
- In each MPI process should compute 10 independent time frames. In each time frame, the *points* are parallelized using OpenMP.

The final outputs of my code are 60 data sets that need to be written in 60 separate files. Almost all of communications between nodes are only sending output results from slaves to root. Depending on whether the root process work or be idle I can design root and slaves in multiple ways:

1. In first implementation, the root process (node 0) is doing computation as well as slave nodes (nodes 1 to 5), so each has to compute 10 frames. In all nodes (either root or slaves) output data of each of the 10 time frame are written to file immediately after they are computed (if it's in root), or send back to the root node (if it's in slave node).

   Obviously this is a wrong approach since root is busy, root and slaves can not meet to send/receive result, so it blocks slave nodes to iteration over next time frames. For instance slave node 2 should wait till all 10 computations of root finish and then root receive data from node 2, and finally node 2 moves to the next time frame computation.
2. To avoid blockage, I can send back slave's results by keeping them on MPI's buffer, so slaves are free to move onto the next time frame iteration. However, the data are taking a lot of memory and it might not be a good idea to have 10 huge data sets waiting on buffer till root node receive then at the end of it's job.
3. Instead of buffering data, slaves can send data at the end rather sending them right after they are computed. That is, slave node 2 computes all 10 time frames without sending them. Meanwhile the root process is almost finished computation of it's 10 frames at the same time. At the end all slave nodes send their results to root node. This is effective since (A) root is not idle, (B) there is no blockage. However the problem is that memory on the slave nodes are limited and they can not keep all 10 time frame results. It is better to send results back to root process right after they are computed, and then clear memory for next iteration.
4. Or do not use root process for any computation. Each slave has to compute 60/(6-1)=12 time frames, and root node only waits for receiving data. The problem is that root node has 20 idle threads, only one of them are used for communication while 19 other threads are not used at all.

Could you please let me know that what is the best design for this hybrid parallelization in this case? Is it possible to split root node to 1 + 19 threads, the first thread only be used for receiving and writing data, while the other 19 threads of root perform computation alongside slaves?

Thanks.

Comment: You make no mention of data from worker node X being required later at worker node Y, you write only of worker's sending their data to root.  Perhaps you have a 5th option (possibly others): each worker writes its outputs to a file and proceeds.  At the end of the computation aggregate the separate files.  Personally I doubt that I, or anyone else, can tell you what the best design is for your code on your infrastructure, I think you're going to have to do some experiments, gather some data, and draw your own conclusions.  None of your options strikes me as diabolically slow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @HighPerformanceMark. Node X is not being required later for node Y. I like your suggestion on the 5th option, by writing data on slave nodes and later read files and transfer them back to root at the end. I have implemented all the 4 options and each had their own problem, personally non of them were satisfying , either it crashes due to out of memory on slave node or there are many of idle threads.

Comment: let us assume your master has 8 cores. you can assign 7 cores to do the computation and 1 core to send and recv from slaves and write to file? is that something you have considered? Just curious.